# How to adjust my checkbox text if the text is very long?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have an listview to display all checkbox. The checkbox title can be short or long. But I intent to see the full text. How can i make it to resize it

None, Android 8.0 library is not support due to the app is support Android 8.0 below

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/is_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/photo_layer_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@drawable/textview_style" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your question is unclear, can you elaborate some more by adding what you are trying to do and what you have tried.

Comment: You'll get help faster if you show your what you are currently trying that isn't working.

Comment: Along with `wrap_content` height, u can also set `singleLine` attribute to `false`. and remove `android:maxLines="1"`. If the title is too long, and you want to show it completly, u might need more than one line. or decrease its `size`, if u don't want multiple lines

Comment: @Surbhi i want decrease the title size only

Comment: Either set the size of `photo_layer_title` as `android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"` or set manually the size as `'android:textSize="12sp'` or something according to your requirement

Comment: @Surbhi the text is link with checkbox

Comment: You can do this in your checkbox as well. Give it a try. Try adding any of these lines in your checkbox and add `width` as `match_parent` and `height` as 'wrap_content`

Comment: <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/is_checked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

@Surbhi this only wrap content alrdy

Answer (score 0):

Set your CheckBox width and height to `wrap_context` and also set your row layout (parent of checkbox) width and height to `wrap_content` too.